# Maven dependency plugin weird issue with UnpackDependenciesMojo

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I am using Maven 3.0.3 and suddenly my mvn dependencies plugin started producing an error. 
I've tried to clean the .m2 folder with no luck... Any ideas?

`WARNING: Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.UnpackDependenciesMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/artifact/filter/collection/ArtifactFilterException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2446)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1872)`

and then

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.filter.collection.ArtifactFilterException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)`

Comment: Check out for required jar.

Comment: The jar is there... maven-common-artifact-filters-1.2.jar

Comment: Which version of maven-dependency-plugin do you use? Have warnings during the build? Download problems? Check your build.

Comment: I am using 2.5.1. I've tried to update to 2.8 but the problem remains. I am having this problem when I try to build. No download problems

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Recently I've updated my Xcode and this installed maven 3.2.1 which messed up the classpath... I've modified the symbolic links to point to my 3.0.3 version and it works fine again... Cannot understand why Apple installs stuff without even mentioning it in the update notes...